# Expand the application from the background when BroadcastReceiver is triggered

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I had a need at the time of executing the onReceive method of my BroadcastReceiver to expand applications from the background if it was minimized, but unfortunately I can’t think of this or find on the Internet how to do this. onReceive, when executed, calls an activity that unlocks the phone and turns on the screen. Everything works if the application was expanded and in focus before the screen was locked, but if not, the screen turns on but does not unlock, and even if this is done manually, the new activity does not appear. I just can't figure out what I'm missing.
I tried to set flags in the intent when calling a new activity activityIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
I also tried to use new Handler().Post(() => {});
And call the service from BroadcastReceiver which called the new activity. None of this worked
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you read: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: Yes, I read this, I’m not sure about all the points, but the application has the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, and there is also permission to remove battery and device restrictions

Comment: You are trying to 'unlock' the device based on background notification? Only a system level app, MDM or custom ROM may be able to do that. Otherwise for a consumer device there needs to be user interaction to 'unlock'. Not clear why using a notification for getting an activity to launch won't fit your needs: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation

Comment: The problem is not in unlocking, but in the fact that the new activity does not appear when the application is minimized by the user

Comment: In general, on a consumer device, user action is required to bring anything to foreground. User clicking a notification gives the OS the affirmative that the user does want to see your activity. How should the user 'affirm' that they want your activity to be brought to foreground?

Comment: An incoming call, I think this is a sufficient reason for the application to come to the foreground

Comment: And the user clicked on the 'accept call' button in the notification. Assuming you are following: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged#no-active and https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/call-notification